# javascript code to lead to current day of week (day.html eg mon.html, tue.html etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  a "proceed" button that leads to a certain day of the week (sun-sat), I want the button to lead to the current day of the week using javascript, my site dundaah.com
so far I have

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var links = new Array(7);
    links[0] = "docs/sun.html" 
 links[1] = "docs/mon.html" 
 links[2] = "docs/tue.html" 
 links[3] = "docs/wed.html" 
 links[4] = "docs/thur.html" 
 links[5] = "docs/fri.html" 
 links[6] = "docs/sun.html" 

    var n = links[d.getDay()];
    window.location=links[myFunction]
}
</script>
```

Comment: var d = new Date(); After this use d.getDay(); and you will get 0 for sunday, 1 for monday, 2 for tuesday ...  like that. I think this hint is enough

Comment: What problem are you having specifically? Asking a concrete question will help people answer.

Comment: i want my 'proceed' button to lead to a html page based on the current date eg proceed=thursday,html

Comment: OK, you've said what you want. So what's the problem with the code you posted? What does, or doesn't it do?

Comment: "*I want*" is a statement, not a question. Please take the time to define the problem you have with your current code as requested by alexroussos and j08691.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var days = ["sun","mon","tue","wed","thur","fri","sat"];
        window.location = days[new Date().getDay()] + ".html";
    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Today's Link</button>
```

Comment: No problemo! I lived off of this website for the longest time so now I have decided to give back a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line. It makes no sense:

```
window.location=links[myFunction]
```

With this:

```
window.location=n;
```